# remove xml tags but leave its name vb.net jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, xml, vb.net

I have a xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:PersonaRCV xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:Identificacion>201232934</xs:Identificacion>
    <xs:Nombre>MAX Luis</xs:Nombre> 
    <xs:Edad>34</xs:Edad><xs:ExtensionData />
    <xs:AbuelosMaternos>
        <xs:ExtensionData />
        <xs:Abuela>
            <xs:ExtensionData />
            <xs:Identificacion>000000000</xs:Identificacion>
            <xs:Nombre>Juana Porras</xs:Nombre>
        </xs:Abuela>
    </xs:AbuelosMaternos>   
</xs:PersonaRCV>
```

I want it to look like this in my aspx page:

```
PersonaRCV:   
   Identificacion: 201232934  
   Nombre: MAX Luis
   Edad: 34
   AbuelosMaternos: 
      Abuela:
      Identificacion: 000000000
      Nombre: Juana Porras
```

I manage to present the entire xml indented in the page with this function:

```
    Public Function FormatXml(ByVal sUnformattedXml As String) As String
    'load unformatted xml into a dom
    Dim xd As New XmlDocument()
    Try
        xd.LoadXml(sUnformattedXml)

        'will hold formatted xml
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

        'pumps the formatted xml into the StringBuilder above
        Dim sw As New StringWriter(sb)

        'does the formatting
        Dim xtw As XmlTextWriter = Nothing

        Try
            'point the xtw at the StringWriter
            xtw = New XmlTextWriter(sw)

            'we want the output formatted
            xtw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented

            'get the dom to dump its contents into the xtw 
            xd.WriteTo(xtw)
        Finally
            'clean up even if error
            If xtw IsNot Nothing Then
                xtw.Close()
            End If
        End Try
        Return sb.ToString()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    'return the formatted xml
    Return sUnformattedXml
End Function
```

and i called it in my aspx like this:

```
<pre><asp:Label ID="LBXML" runat="server"><%# Server.HtmlEncode(FormatXml(Eval("Respuesta")))%></asp:Label></pre>
```

Finally the code seen with Firebug looks like this:

```
&lt;xs:PersonaRCV xmlns:xsi=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance&quot; xmlns:xs=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema&quot;&gt;
    &lt;xs:Identificacion&gt;401690010&lt;/xs:Identificacion&gt;
    &lt;xs:Nombre&gt;MAX FRANCISCO&lt;/xs:Nombre&gt;
```

I was trying to do something with jquery replace:

```
var queHay = $("#MostrarEsconder" + myVal + " span").html();
queHay.replace('/&lt;xs:/', '');
```

but i can't get it to work.
Anyone can suggest something to get my results as i want them? with jquery or in codebehind in my FormatXML function!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found an answer for this.
using Jquery i replace all the characters i didn't need.
You can see it here:

```
 var queHay = $("#MostrarEsconder" + myVal + " span").html();
 queHay = queHay.replace(/\&lt;\?xml.*\&gt;/g, '');
 queHay = queHay.replace(/xmlns:xsi.*\&gt;/g, '');
 queHay = queHay.replace(/\&lt;\/xs:.*\&gt;/g, '');
 queHay = queHay.replace(/ExtensionData.*\/\&gt;/g, '');
 queHay = queHay.replace(/\&gt;/g, ': ');
 queHay = queHay.replace(/\&lt\;xs\:/g, '');
 $("#MostrarEsconder" + myVal + " span").html(queHay);
```

Answer (score 0):

Encode just the string that gets passed to your FormatXML function instead of encoding the response...

```
<%# FormatXml(Server.HtmlEncode(Eval("Respuesta")))%>
```

Comment: the problem with decode is that i loose all the xml tags, and as you can read in my question i need to keep the name of the tag! also if i use decode i loose the indentation!

Comment: i've tried that and the entire xml string shows in only one row.

Comment: You may also need to use the Server.HtmlDecode at the top of your FormatXML so it loads correctly.

Comment: Oh ok, well then you're going to have to do some template magic by binding the xml data source to a gridview or repeater item control (or have your FormatXML replace Line Breaks and tabs with <br> tags).

Comment: i'm using a repeater for every xml i found the answer with jquery. thank you very much.